# Jenkinsfile access existing environment variable

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

How do I access an existing environment variable `SOME_VAR` inside of the `environment` block?

I want to redefine it under a new name `NEW_VAR`?

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label any
    }
    environment {
        SECRET = credentials('secret-credential') // works as expected
        NEW_VAR = ? // get from different env variable
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo "SECRET=${env.SECRET}"
                echo "NEW_VAR=${env.NEW_VAR}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried so far:

```
NEW_VAR = SOME_VAR        // fails build
NEW_VAR = env.SOME_VAR    // fails build
NEW_VAR = ${env.SOME_VAR} // fails build
NEW_VAR = env('SOME_VAR') // does not fail, but NEW_VAR is null
NEW_VAR = env(SOME_VAR)   // does not fail, but NEW_VAR is null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
environment {
    NEW_VAR = "${env.SOME_VAR}"
}
```

This way you're doing [string interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_string_interpolation), and then assigning string value to the new var.
Just tested, this should work.